# ListView Search is not Working Properly

Tags: android

I have started learning android some days back 
i am working on list views i want to search items in list view. gi have gone through many post  and wrote following code but some how it is not working.

QyestionActivity

```
public class QuestionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String filepath = null;
String question_filepath = null;
Controller c;
ListView question_list_view;
EditText txt_search;
ArrayList<SingleQuestion> question_list;
Main_QuestionList_Adapter questionlistAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    filepath = Constant.application_file_path;
    question_filepath = filepath + "questions.txt";
    File test_fiFile = new File(question_filepath);
    if (!test_fiFile.exists()) {
        copyAssets();
    }

    new ParseQuestionFIle().parseQuestionfile(question_filepath);
    c = Controller.getController();
    question_list = c.getQuestions().getQuestions();
    question_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_questionlit);
    txt_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    questionlistAdapter = new Main_QuestionList_Adapter(
            QuestionActivity.this);
    question_list_view.setAdapter(questionlistAdapter);
    question_list_view.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    txt_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            questionlistAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            questionlistAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            questionlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            question_list_view.setAdapter(questionlistAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


}
```

Adapter Class

public class Main_QuestionList_Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

```
Controller c = Controller.getController();
ArrayList<SingleQuestion> questions_aerraylist;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
SingleQuestion singleQuestion;
Filter filter;
public Main_QuestionList_Adapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    questions_aerraylist = new ArrayList<SingleQuestion>();
    questions_aerraylist = c.getQuestions().getQuestions();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questions_aerraylist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View currentView, ViewGroup parentView) {
    QuestioViewHolder questionviewholder;

    if (currentView == null) {
        currentView = inflater
                .inflate(
                        com.example.ten_step.R.layout.main_question_list_adapter_view,
                        null);
        questionviewholder = new QuestioViewHolder();
        currentView.setTag(questionviewholder);
    } else {
        questionviewholder = (QuestioViewHolder) currentView.getTag();
    }
    questionviewholder.question_text_view = (TextView) currentView
            .findViewById(com.example.ten_step.R.id.txt_question_text);
    singleQuestion = new SingleQuestion();
    singleQuestion = questions_aerraylist.get(position);
    questionviewholder.question_text_view.setText(singleQuestion
            .getQuestion().toString());
    questionviewholder.question_text_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(singleQuestion != null)
                {
                    c.setSelected_question(questions_aerraylist.get(position));
                    Toast.makeText(context, c.getSelected_question().getQuestion(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please Tr Againg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    return currentView;
}

class QuestioViewHolder {
    TextView question_text_view;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
      if (filter == null) {
            filter = new QuestionFilter();
        }
        return filter;
}



private class QuestionFilter extends Filter {

    ArrayList<SingleQuestion> actual_list;
    ArrayList<SingleQuestion> sorted_list;

    Controller controller;

    public QuestionFilter() {
        actual_list = new ArrayList<SingleQuestion>();
        controller = Controller.getController();
        actual_list = controller.getQuestions().getQuestions();
        sorted_list = new ArrayList<SingleQuestion>();

    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence searchQuer) {
        String search_query  = searchQuer.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if(search_query != null || search_query.length() !=0 )
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < actual_list.size() ; i++)
            {
                if(actual_list.get(i).getQuestion().toLowerCase().contains(search_query)  && !sorted_list.contains(actual_list.get(i)) )
                {
                    sorted_list.add(actual_list.get(i));
                }
            }
            if(sorted_list.size() !=0)
            {
                result.values = sorted_list;
                result.count = sorted_list.size();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.values = actual_list;
            result.count = actual_list.size();
        }
        c.getQuestions().setQuestion((ArrayList<SingleQuestion>) result.values);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence searchQuer, FilterResults results) {
         ArrayList<SingleQuestion> new_sorted_list = (ArrayList<SingleQuestion>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
             c.getQuestions().setQuestion(new_sorted_list);
            // notifyDataSetChanged();
         } else {
             notifyDataSetInvalidated();
         }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi down voter please add your comment before down vote. so i will correct my self if i have done some thing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done SEARCH IN LIST VIEW in bit different manner.
I have Used Textwatcher Instead of implementing Filterable interface to adapter.

Please Take a look at following code and provide suggestion if you have.

```
public class QuestionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String filepath = null;
String question_filepath = null;
Controller c;
ListView question_list_view;
EditText txt_search;
ArrayList<SingleQuestion> question_list;
Main_QuestionList_Adapter questionlistAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    filepath = Constant.application_file_path;
    question_filepath = filepath + "questions.txt";
    File test_fiFile = new File(question_filepath);
    if (!test_fiFile.exists()) {
        copyAssets();
    }

    new ParseQuestionFIle().parseQuestionfile(question_filepath);
    c = Controller.getController();
    question_list = c.getQuestions().getQuestions();
    question_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_questionlit);
    txt_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    questionlistAdapter = new Main_QuestionList_Adapter(
            QuestionActivity.this , c.getQuestions().getQuestions());
    question_list_view.setAdapter(questionlistAdapter);
    question_list_view.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    txt_search.addTextChangedListener(searchTextChangeListener);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

TextWatcher searchTextChangeListener = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        ArrayList<SingleQuestion> defaultQuestinList = c.getQuestions()
                .getQuestions();
        if (s.length() > 0) {

            Set<SingleQuestion> sortedQuestionSet = new HashSet<SingleQuestion>();
            int questionListCount = defaultQuestinList.size();
            String searchQuery = s.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < questionListCount; i++) {
                if (defaultQuestinList.get(i).getQuestion().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(searchQuery)) {
                    sortedQuestionSet.add(defaultQuestinList.get(i));
                }
            }
            ArrayList<SingleQuestion> sortedQuestionList = new ArrayList<SingleQuestion>();
            sortedQuestionList.addAll(sortedQuestionSet);
            questionlistAdapter = new Main_QuestionList_Adapter(QuestionActivity.this ,sortedQuestionList);
            question_list_view.setAdapter(questionlistAdapter);
        }
        else
        {
            Questions q  = c.getQuestions();
            q.setQuestion(defaultQuestinList);

            questionlistAdapter = new Main_QuestionList_Adapter(QuestionActivity.this ,defaultQuestinList);
            question_list_view.setAdapter(questionlistAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

> Above code worked for me totally fine .